# I can't set main Class variable in onCreate Method

Tags: java, android, class

Main class has two variables that want to access another class:

```
public class MyClassA extends Activity {
int i = 1;
Button b1; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.i = 31;
        this.b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        ~~
    }
 }
```

Second class want to call variables in mainClass object:

```
public class MyclassB implements OnClickListener{
     MyClassA mainClass = new MyClassA();
     Button btn = mainClass.b1;
     int n = mainClass.i;
     public void OnClick(View arg0){
         Log.v("btn:",btn);
         Log.v("int:",n);
     }

     //btn returns null;
     //int returns 1;
```

But `onCreate` method not set variables..

Why not set main class variables like `this.i=31` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you just instantiate your activity like a simple class, it won't execute `onCreate()` that is why `i` value stays as `1` . onCreate() will be called when you use `Intent` and `Activity`.

As commented, you may need to use either Inner classes (or) anonymous class. read this [documentation](http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/14/implementing-listeners-in-your-android-java-application/) for more info.

Comment: but first time onCreate changed "i" and "b1" values after used this.i,this.b1,how can i call changed variables another class?

Comment: You can make them static, but remember that may introduce some other headaches. It seems you are looking for listener, then as kumar suggested, go with inner class/annonymous class. That may resolve your issue.

Comment: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-innder-classes_android/ : 404 error

Comment: can we call method like mainClass.getValues()?

Comment: if method is static, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Use **Inner Class**.

```
public class MyClassA extends Activity {
int i = 1;
Button b1; 
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.i = 31;
        this.b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        ~~
    }


   class MyclassB implements OnClickListener{

// You can directly access the members of the Outer class from the Inner Class

     Button btn = b1;     
     int n = i;

     public void OnClick(View arg0){
         Log.v("btn:",btn);
         Log.v("int:",n);
     }

 }

}
```

Comment: is there any way access members of main class from other filed class?

Comment: 2 WAYS..Pass the Activity(ie Context) of the Class which extends the Activity to the another java class which DoesNot extends Activity. Or try making the members of the class which extends Activity as static.

Comment: can i call method like mainClass.getValues() ?